# How to "make a simple Password Autofill Chrome Extension"?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, autofill

I want to make simple Chrome Extension for autofilling the user credentials by fetching the data from a native java Password Manager program installed on the Computer.

I`m a noob. Please Guide me.

Comment: Have you tried to read the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) first? It will help you to understand the basic concept and [debugging extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging) works.

Comment: Yes I know the basics how to make an extension. I want to learn how to make an Extension which will scan the page and search for input fields, recognize their types and fill it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how you should connect the extension with the native client you should be looking at [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging).

I advise against making something this security sensitive yourself if you are a self-described noob though.

Comment: I just want to make it for my school project.

Comment: I wanted to reply in the other thread, but I don't have enough reps for that yet. You should break your question down more and ask/figure them out separately.